# Duplicate ListFragment entries when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes, android-listfragment

So, I'm developing an app with fragments, and everything is fine, except that when I change orientation the entries on my `ListFragment`  duplicate like this:

[image: Normal][image: Landscape]

And when I go back to portrait mode, the items are still duplicated; until I kill the process and restart.

To populate the list I'm using an `AsyncTaskLoader`, but it only runs once, when the application starts for the first time; then my adapter gets filled with the info for the rows.

I'm not using the `<fragment>` tag in my main.xml, the fragment is added by code in the 'parent' activity like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        TodoListFragment fragment = new TodoListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.fragment_list_container, fragment,
                LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

The replace was and add, but changed trying to test if it made any difference, it didn't.
I also tried using the `setRetainInstance(true)` method, to no avail.

I'm stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code in your ` onResume`?

Comment: on the activity no, on the fragment yes, it updates the adapter sending a `notifyDataSetChanged()` so it refreshes, but this does not make any difference in the duplication thing, because commenting it incurs in the same behavior.

Comment: are you sure you just have notifyDataSetChanged(), my possible conclusion is the arraylist or whatever backing the adapter has the data being added once more

Comment: You say the AsyncTaskLoader only runs when the app starts... On orientation change the app is restarting, so maybe it's running a second time?

Comment: @Barak ha, that was it, I was forgetting to call the `clear()` method in my adapter in the `onLoadFinished()`. that made the trick, will you be so kind to make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the AsyncTaskLoader only runs when the app starts... On orientation change the app is restarting, so maybe it's running a second time?